# statsmodels.api Logit giving LinAlgError

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

I am trying to do a Logit regression for my data, but I ran into a problem that whenever I try to fit it, I get an error:

```
LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

I can not understand why that happens. My dataframe is NOT full of zeroes/ones, but it does contain only a small percentage of 1s. Here is the sample:

```
formula = 'wage ~ I( (33 > age) & (age >= 65) ) + I( (50 > age) & (age >= 33) ) + I( (65 > age) & (age >= 50) )' 
test = [0 for i in range(3000)]
test[256] = 1
df['wage'] = test
ft = smf.logit(formula=formula, data=df).fit(disp=0)
```

How do I get rid of this? There is no way that you can't fit a model with a small percentage of 1s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you specify the interaction variable results is really weird:

1. `I( (33 > age) & (age >= 65) )` : this would be all zeros, you cannot have age < 33 and age >65 so you cannot fit this.
2. If you set that above to be `I( (33 > age) | (age >= 65) )` your model matrix will still be rank deficient (i.e over determined) because all your three predictors will be a linear combination of your intercept.
3. If you fit without an intercept, it might work depending on how many positive classes you have.

There are [known issues with logistic regression on imbalanced data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/does-an-unbalanced-sample-matter-when-doing-logistic-regression). In your case, the intercepts or the class with all zeros as response will be problematic.

If your aim is to find which class has a positive association with the age group, considering using a fisher.test

If the aim is to predict.. I don't think there's a way out of this with imbalanced data.